# VBA -have to delete rows by complex comparrision among value in different columns on conditions?

Tags: vba, excel

As you can see below, please read through carefully.

Certain tests are done on  a particular object with test ids , datedone and results in the table below and consideration of results has to be done based on below explained tasks

1-Task 1

if the same test is done with different test id, for example here "AAA" has done three times then i should take the row with highest testid. among here 1,2,5 respectively for "AAA", i should only have the row with 5 and remaining two i should delete.

2- Task 2

if the same test is done for same test id multiple times i should consider the result & datedone columns,it has parts please read here

-- part 1: if any one of the result is failed then the test is failed, for example here for test "CCC" the 'test id' is 2,2 & result is passed, failed respectively. then as testid is same i should consider result and always the failed result i should consider and i should delete the row that has passed in it.

--part 2: if both of the test results is passed or failed then i should consider the datedone column and consider the one that is latest and delete older one. for example here "HHH"test is done twice with testid 6 and both the times it passed. but it has done at different datedone 15.10.2013& 25.10.2014, so i has to consider 25.10.2014 and delete row with 15.10.2013.

3.Type 3
if everyvalue is same from tests to result then i need to delete any one of them.for example here tests"BBB".

```
Tests    Datedone    Test Id      Result        
AAA     13.10.2011      1         failed        

BBB     13.10.2011      1         passed         

CCC     24.10.2011      2         passed           

AAA     15.10.2011      2         passed        

BBB     13.10.2011      1         passed         

CCC     31.12.2015      2         failed         

HHH     15.10.2013      6         passed         

HHH     25.10.2014      6         passed       

AAA     31.10.2015      5         passed
```

Column 1,2,3 are TEST,Datedone & Testid respectively in code. This code i have done only when i have to consider latest result but not working properly anyways

```
Sub formattest1consolidate()
 'not working
 Dim i, j, rangevale,  As Long
 Dim cell, rng,  As range
 Sheets("").Activate
 rangevale = range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
 For Each cell In range("A2:A" & rangevale)
  For i = 1 To rangevale
   For j = i + 1 To rangevale
      If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(j, 1) And _
         Cells(i, 3) = Cells(j, 3) And _
         Cells(i, 2) = Cells(j, 2) Then

        'do nothing

      ElseIf Cells(i, 1) = Cells(j, 1) And _
             Cells(i, 3) > Cells(j, 3) Then

        rng.Item(j).EntireRow.Delete

      ElseIf Cells(i, 1) = Cells(j, 1) And _
             Cells(i, 3) < Cells(j, 3) Then

         rng.Item(i).EntireRow.Delete

      ElseIf Cells(i, 1) = Cells(j, 1) And _
             Cells(i, 3) = Cells(j, 3) And _
             Cells(i, 2) > Cells(j, 2) Then

         rng.Item(j).EntireRow.Delete

      ElseIf Cells(i, 1) = Cells(j, 1) And _
             Cells(i, 3) = Cells(j, 3) And _
             Cells(i, 2) < Cells(j, 2) Then

         rng.Item(i).EntireRow.Delete

      End If
    Next j
  Next i
Next cell

End Sub
```

output looks like this

```
 Tests    Datedone    Test Id      Result        

 BBB     13.10.2011      1         passed         

 CCC     31.12.2015      2         failed         

 HHH     25.10.2014      6         passed

 AAA     31.10.2015      5         passed
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Please at least format your code so that's it's readable, I can't bring myself  to follow that `If/ElseIf` block. Also `but not working properly anyways` - what isn't workng? This question is totally unclear

Comment: i will do it from next time, as i have tried my best to make it clear. may be i should think from others point of view also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without VBA.

Set up your data in a table like the screenshot below then apply the sort as shown. Sort follows your logical steps.

[image]

Then once the sort is complete remove the duplicates as shown here.

[image]

Your results will end up like this:

[image]

If you would like the code to do this, using this same commands, it is below:

```
Sub RemoveLines()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws

    With .Range("A1:D10")

        With .Sort

            With .SortFields
                .Clear
                .Add Key:=Range("A2:A10"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                .Add Key:=Range("C2:C10"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                .Add Key:=Range("D2:D10"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                .Add Key:=Range("B2:B10"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            End With

            .SetRange Range("A1:D10")
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply

        End With

        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

    End With

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, it has some bugs but it was the solution what i was looking and i successfully sorted the data accordingly.

Comment: great @subha. if it was the solution you were looking for, please mark as answered